# Laravel - Notification Customizing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-notification

So I'm sending mails with using Laravel notification. It can be very easy question but I couldnt find any answer. When I check the mails in my e-mail, the header part or i dont know how to describe it has always tag : "example". What I should add to change that tag "Example"??

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->greeting('New Password')
                    ->subject('New Password - zzz')
                    ->line('Keep your password safe, and have fun!')
                    ->line('Your new password is ' . $this->password)
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
```

it looks like :

> Example "gotl.and.gotl@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your settings.  These are coming from `config/mail.php`.  You will likely need to add or update them in your `.env` file.

Comment: Yeah this is the true answer.. I mean its something so easy but there is no explanation about it. thank you for remind me and people like me.

Comment: Can I customize it for every notification I send?

Comment: Yeah, just chain on `->from($emailAddress, $name)`

Comment: I did it but its still saying "example". I have changed infos in config/mail.. but still same. why?..

Comment: No no its ok its working fine, just i saw it wrong.. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You should run in console:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

and then choose `lluminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider` (assuming you are using one of latest Laravel versions)

and as a result you should get:

```
Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views] To [/resources/views/vendor/notifications]
Publishing complete.
```

Then you can take a look at `/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php` file content.